# I want append my card to another html page

Tags: html

> Here I get all values from one html now i want append to another html page . how to i do?

```js
$('.fa-cart-plus ').click(function () {
    var images = $(this).attr('src');
    var price = $(this).attr('data-name');
    var con = $(this, '.modal-body>p').parent().html();
    $('#tom').append("<div class='card' data-name=" + price + " > <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal'>&times;</button><img src=" + images + " ><div>" + con + "</div></div > ")

});
```

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, there are two html files in your app and you want the content from first page to be available on the other when you redirect.
If so, you need to save your data as you'll lose your data when redirected.
 The best way will be to save the data to the backend database. However, if you do not have the database, you can use `localStorage`.
Try this:

```
// ......
var con = $(this, '.modal-body>p').parent().html();
var cards=[];   // Added code from here
cards.append("{your_content}");    //Replace `{your-content}` with your content
localStorage.setItem('cards', {cards});
```

Now at the other route, you can get data from it using:

```
const cards = localStorage.getItem('cards');
$("#tom").html(cards);
```

Refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Hope it helps. Cheers!